# Type Convertion of randomByteString from Raaz Crypto Library

Tags: haskell

I was trying to use randomByteString from [Raaz](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/raaz-0.2.0/docs/Raaz-Random.html) Crypto Library. Facing some Issue of type convertion  in this code

`str = randomByteString (42::ALIGN)`

here this code returns `str` of type `RT mem ByteString`, how do I convert it's type to `ByteString`?

Comment: It's a monad.  Have you tried using `securely` or, if you'd like, `insecurely`.  For example, `securely str :: IO ByteString`.

Comment: I tried this (`str :: IO ByteString; str = securely $  randomByteString (42::ALIGN)`)  from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/raaz-0.2.0/docs/Raaz-Random.html this link, but it gives an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `randomByteString` function requires a length argument, which is polymorphic, and yields a monadic result which must be ran using either `securely` or `insecurely`.  Putting these together and remembering to give explicit types so there are no ambiguities we get:

```
securely (randomByteString (10 :: BYTES Int) :: RandM ByteString)
```

In a full program you usually wouldn't need these extra type signatures since they'd naturally appear in function signatures, be inferable, or otherwise appear as typed fields in your program.

Comment: @MaheshUligade Since this answered your question accept the answer. To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer.  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.